# Get Movies Name From Facebook Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying get Name from Movies who I like with Graph API, I using Eclipse and Android SDK.

In this line I get a error:

```
JSONArray moviesJA = (JSONArray)graph.getProperty("movies");
```

I have permission to get this type of data.

Here is full method:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Response result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    ArrayList<String> movies = new ArrayList<String>();

    GraphObject graph = result.getGraphObject();

    JSONArray moviesJA = (JSONArray)graph.getProperty("movies");
    if(moviesJA.length() > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i<moviesJA.length(); i++){
            JSONObject movie = moviesJA.optJSONObject(i);
            if(movie!= null){
                movies.add(movie.optString("name"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Someone could help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please give us also the logcat?

Comment: Can you attach (or link) to an example of the JSON response?